# Product of linear factors

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I have a polynomial $h=T^5+6T^4+6T^3+T+2$ in  ring $\mathbb{F_7}[T]$. I should write it as a product of linear factors. So $h=(T+1)^2 (T^3+4T^2-3T+2)$. But $-3$ in $\mathbb{F_7}$ is $4$, so that polynomial is equal to $h=(T+1)^2 (T^3+4T^2+4T+2)$.  Is it correct?

Comment: It's not a product of linear factors.

Comment: there should be "as a product of linear factors and polynomial without zeros". In this case is it correct?

Comment: You should verify that the second polynomial has no zeros in $\Bbb F_7$

Comment: In particular: note that $T-3$ is a linear factor that you've forgotten.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can factor the polynomial as
$$
h(T) = (T+1)^2(T+4)^2(T^2 + 4)
$$

Answer (score 0):

You can't write it as a product of linear factors. Actually, $3$ is a root of the second factor, which factors as;
$$T^3+4T^2-3T+2=(T-3)(T^2+4),$$
and $-4=3$ is not a square in $\mathbf F_7$.